# Как посмотреть версию Linux в терминале?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Как посмотреть версию Linux в терминале?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Узнать, 32 или 64 bit:

```
uname -m
```

> ```
> $ uname -m
> x86_64
> ```

Еще варианты [узнать версию linux](http://jeka.by/ask/157/linux-get-version/):

```
cat /etc/issue
```

> ```
> $ cat /etc/issue
> Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS \n \l
> ```

```
lsb_release -a
```

> ```
> $ lsb_release -a
> No LSB modules are available.
> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
> Description:  Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
> Release:  14.04
> Codename: trusty
> ```

Посмотреть версию ядра linux:

```
uname -r
```

> ```
> $ uname -r
> 3.13.0-87-generic
> ```

Comment: Данные здесь комманды не помогут узнать версию linux, ибо linux - ядро. Поэтому единственный верный ответ был дан @alexander barakin`ом

Comment: @Ancient добавил команду для версии ядра.

Answer (score 25):

версию программы *linux*, которая запущена в данный момент, можно посмотреть, например, командой (приведён и пример вывода):

```
$ uname -r
3.13.0-57-generic
```

или даже:

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.13.0-57-generic (buildd@brownie) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #95-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 09:28:15 UTC 2015
```

---

версию же дистрибутива можно посмотреть, например, командой (приведён и пример вывода):

```
$ lsb_release -r
Release:    14.04
```

больше информации — с опцией `-a` (приведён и пример вывода):

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

это если установлена программа *lsb_release*. к сожалению, до сих пор не во всех дистрибутивах она устанавливается по умолчанию. тогда стоит воспользоваться командой (приведён и пример вывода):

```
$ cat /etc/*release*
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.4 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Answer (score 4):

Например следующим образом (может не работать в старых версиях):

```
lsb_release -a
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать выполнить такую команду:

```
cat /etc/*-release
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ python -mplatform
Linux-4.2.0-36-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть ещё консольная утилита **[screenFetch](https://github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch)**:

[image: screenFetch]