# Неправильное распознавание клавиш клавиатуры Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

*Alt L/R, Super L/R, Shift R, Control L/R* читает как *Shift L*
Как исправить и чем вызвано такое странное поведение?

Comment: приведите, пожаулуйста, описание одного события (keypress или keyrelease) для каких-нибудь из перечисленных клавиш. например, вывод команды: `$xev | awk -F'[ )]+' '/^KeyPress/ { a[NR+2] } NR in a { printf "%-3s %s\n", $5, $8 }' ` (запустите и понажимайте нужные клавиши).

Comment: ![Скрин терминала](https://pp.vk.me/c636726/v636726207/381ad/uZ94b7s4B9A.jpg)

Comment: 1. лучше было написать это в виде текста внутри вопроса, нажав [edit]. 2. раз эти значения совпадают, приведите заодно чуть больше подробностей — пару секций *keypress* целиком из вывода `$ xev`. в вывод попадает много информации, поэтому скопируйте только одну секцию и только для одной-двух из перечисленных вами клавиш.

Comment: учтите, что при нажатии (и быстром отпускании) клавиш должно генерироваться ровно две секции — *keypress* и *keyrelease*. если у вас их генерируется больше, тоже упомяните об этом. // и, кстати, укажите [версию программы linux](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/525473/178576)